# Turn off viewer icons (and names)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, google-slides

I'd like to share a Google file (document/sheet/slide) but have the little viewer color bubbles in the top-right corner disabled such that viewers can't see how many others are viewing concurrently.

To clarify, I know about [setting "Anonymous Animals"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en) (which turn viewer names into anonymized images/names when users aren't within your work/school domain) but is there an option to turn off concurrent viewership visualization altogether on a shared file?

Comment: Have you considered to embed the file in a Google Site or web page? Will you send the link to the file by email or post it somewhere?

Comment: Rubén's solution seems to be the best, there doesn't seem to be a way to turn off viewer icons or names in vanilla google sheets, it simply breaks too many features, also you have to consider the new edit history feature in the right click menu which will let you see names as well.